# Storing a byte array in a flatbuffers table

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, flatbuffers

I'm trying to store a byte array in a Flatbuffers table, and I think this is how the schema should look like:

```
table VoiceData { 
    compressed_data:[byte];
}
```

Then, in code I call `CreateCompressedDataVector`, but it will only take an object of type sbyte[] and not byte[], so I'm not sure how to progress.

This is the complete code snippet:

[image]

I'm new to the whole FlatBuffers thing, so I don't really know what I'm doing - could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

A flatbuffers `byte` is a signed `int8` (https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_writing_schema.html). So in C# you have to use `sbyte` as the native type to indicate the correct signedness.

For more details, here is the [list of conversions](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/8468eab83bacc8bbd6cb5ae22197af06a9437b2d/include/flatbuffers/idl.h#L50) of flatbuffers `byte` into other languages. C# is 5th column.

For flatbuffers `ubyte`, the [C# version is `byte`](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/include/flatbuffers/idl.h#L51)

Comment: Thank you! Now, how do I get a hold of the byte array again when deserializing? `GetCompressedDataBytes()` sounds promising, but that returns an Array segment, and not a byte array

Comment: Flatbuffers avoids copies in the API, so it's probably returning an ArraySegment backed by the buffer. You have to explicitly copy out of the ArraySegment if you want to get the bytes. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.arraysegment-1.copyto?view=net-6.0#system-arraysegment-1-copyto(-0())